# How can I 'animate' sequential underlining or highlighting of individual String characters within a UILabel? [Swift]

Tags: swift, animation, uilabel

I am displaying a string of dash-separated letters and numbers in a UILabel (e.g., "1 - B - 9 - J - G - 5").  I am hoping to come up with a way of 'animating' them so each non-dash character is underlined or highlighted in sequential order, at one second intervals (e.g., '1' is highlighted for one second, then '1' returns to default state and 'B' is highlighted for one second, then 'B' returns to default state and '9' is highlighted for one second, etc.).  I'm an amateur but have tried to research this on my own and have asked for help elsewhere.  Someone suggested individual UILabels for each character, which I could do but seems pretty clunky, and someone else suggested attributed strings, which seems very promising but I can't figure out how to fully execute.  I've done some reading and I think I understand how I could highlight or underline individual characters at specific positions, but I can't quite get my head around how to set up the incrementing/timing aspect of it.  A few other details that may or may not matter:

- The string content is not static- it is generated randomly into a new array and then converted to a string each time the app runs.
- It doesn't have to be underlining or highlighting specifically if something else is easier (e.g., text color change) - I just need to spotlight each character for one second.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using successive NSAttributedString values assigned to the label's `attributedText`, similar to the technique I suggest at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056895/341994.

[image]

The key lines of the code are:

```
let range = NSRange(location: i*4, length: 1)
let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(string: s)
mas.addAttributes([.backgroundColor:UIColor.yellow], range: range)
self.label.attributedText = mas
```

...where `i` increases each time.